# Find number of combinations of ordered set using multiple summations

Tags: java, c++, sum, combinations, combinatorics

This is in regards to a problem for finding a number of combinations of an ordered set, where the elements have constraints.

As an example:

a+b+c+d+e=635, which may be...

[0-90] + [1-120] + [50-150] + [20-200] + [30-250] = 635

One solution uses multiple summations, as it was answered in the mathematics stack exchange.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159197/combinatorics-using-constraints-and-ordered-set

Can someone please give a general idea of the procedure or pseudo-code to solving this type of problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Homework? What did you try? Also, language specific tags would be highly relevant.

Comment: Not homework. I am hoping someone understands the mathematical procedure of using multiple summations as exemplified in the math exchange link, as I do not. I'm not sure if the multiple summations should be nested loops adding 1 to the value elements. I just don't understand the mathematical equation well enough, such as d=max(c+1,20) as an index of summation and the multiple summations.

Comment: This question might also be better suited to math.stackexchange.com; although you will likely get an answer here it wouldn't hurt to ask there as well. The equation you got isn't particularly well suited to computation; computing it directly would entail counting one-by-one.

Comment: This question was asked first on the math stackexchange. The link is included in this question posted here. It was answered with a summation equation, also a suggestion to ask how to code it on possibly this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bunch of nested for-loops is the simplest way to do it.

Pseudocode:

```
let combinations = 0;
for a = 0 to 90
    for b = max(a+1, 1) to 120
        for c = max(b+1, 50) to 150
            for d = max(c+1, 20) to 200
                let e = 635 - a - b - c - d;
                if max(d+1, 50) <= e <= 250
                    let combinations = combinations + 1
```

**Update**

The above can be optimised a bit, but you end up with a specific, rather than general, solution.

You can observe that `(a+1) >= 1` is always true, so we can get rid of the `max` call in the assignment to `b`.  Likewise, `(c+1) >= 20` is always true, so the assignment to `d` can be simplified.

You can also see that the maximum possible value of `a + b + c + d` is 540, which gives a minimum possible value of 95 for `e`.  This is greater than the stated lower bound for `e`, so we just have to check that `e >= (d+1)`.

We end up with:

```
let combinations = 0;
for a = 0 to 90
    for b = a+1 to 120
        for c = max(b+1, 50) to 150
            for d = c+1 to 200
                let e = 635 - a - b - c - d;
                if d+1 <= e <= 250
                    let combinations = combinations + 1
```

Comment: Thank you! So this is going through the possibilities, testing and incrementing. I got it, though hoping it wasn't that. This could take a long time to go through each one. If there was another, faster method to obtain the same result, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the solution posted on the math exchange page.  Each sigma sign is a nested `for` loop.  The inner-most term, `x`, is given as an `if`.  Your algorithm should therefore be four nested loops around an if.